# Dual channel audio not playing on Mac Mini Server

Tags: macos, mac, audio

My new Mac Mini Server will not play dual channel audio from Spotify, Quicktime, or iTunes. It plays single channel audio just fine.

Also, the startup chime comes on fine, which I believe is stereo.

I have tried the following:

- Turning up the volume in Audio MIDI Setup
- zapping the PRAM trying it from a new user account
- unplugging any peripherals (all that is now connected is a CAT5 cable and the power cord)
- deleting AirFoil (stopped working right around when I installed it)
- I have a lot of old software which I brought over from my previous machine but I thought that I could troubleshoot that with the new user.

Oh one more thing: I brought the Mac Mini to the Genius Bar. After they zapped the PRAM, the sound worked perfectly for both dual and single channel.

The only difference is the fact that the Mac Mini is connected to an Airport Extreme.

Any troubleshooting avenues you all can suggest?